# R mutating column with dataframe name for a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, lapply

I am trying to automate the creation of a column (titled FXN) for all dataframes in a given list of dataframes, such that the name of the column is generated:

I tried lapply approach, but am not sure how to retrieve the respective file name from each respective listed dataframe

```
#read in list of dataframe (ldf)
ldf <- lapply("directory", read.delim)    

#function to generate column FXN with respective df name
lapply(ldf, function(x) {
mutate(x,
       FXN = deparse(substitute(x)))})
```

However this just results in a column FXN that contains the value x; I would've expected deparse and substitute to pull out respective dataframe names.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `purrr`'s `map2`-function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ldf %>% 
  map2(names(.), ~mutate(.x, FXN = .y))
```